# A question about Cosets that are subsets of each other.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Allow **G** to be a group with **H** and **K** being subgroups. 
If

$Ha\subseteq{Kb}$ for some $a,b\in G$

where Ha is a right coset of H and Kb is the right coset of K

Show

$H\subseteq{K}$

I can show that $x\in{Ha}$ s.t. $x=ha=kb$ for some $h\in{H}$ and $k\in{K}$
I'm not really sure how I would go about showing that $h\in{K}$ which would show that $H\subseteq{K}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Since $Ha\subseteq Kb$, you know that $H\subseteq K(ba^{-1})$. What’s the only coset of $K$ that contains the identity?

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. I don't know why I didn't think of just multiplying by the inverse.

Comment: @BigFudge: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $Ha \subseteq Kb$ then $H \subseteq Kba^{-1}$. Which coset of $K$ contains $e \in H$, the identity element?